# How to insert a field(foreign key) using dropdownlist in asp.net - Basic MVC4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreign-keys, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I get the error,

**Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'DepartmentID'**

for the following code in asp.net mvc using linq object.

(only the necessary part was taken from the entire codes)

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Database** :two tables

(1)departments: int d_id (primary key), string d_name

(2)staffs: int staff_id(primary key), int staff_departmentId(foreign key reference [departments] d_id)

**Model**:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace d.Models
 {

  directoryLinqDataContext objDirectory = new directoryLinqDataContext();

  public IQueryable<department> getDepartments()    
  {
   var allDepartments = objDirectory.departments.Select(x => x);
   return allDepartments;    
  }

 public IQueryable<staff> getStaff()
 {
   var allStaff = objDirectory.staffs.Select(x => x);
   return allStaff;
 }

 public bool commitInsertS(staff s)
 {
   using (objDirectory)
   {
     objDirectory.staffs.InsertOnSubmit(s);
     objDirectory.SubmitChanges();
     return true;
   }
 }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using d.Models;

namespace d.Controllers
{
public class DirController : Controller
{

 public ActionResult staffInsert()
 {
   var q = objDir.getDepartments().Select(d => new { d.d_id, d.d_name });            
   ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(q, "d_id", "d_name", null);

   return View();
 }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult staffInsert(staff s)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     try
     {                    
       objDir.commitInsertS(s);
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     catch
     {
       return View();
     }
  }

  var q = objDir.getDepartments().Select(d => new { d.d_id, d.d_name });

  ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(q.AsEnumerable(), "d_id", "d_name", s.staff_departmentId);

  return View();
}
```

**View**:

```
@model d.Models.staff
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID")
   <input type="submit" value="Insert New Staff" />
 }
@section Scripts{
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

Comment: You get that error message when the `SelectList` is null, which it is when you return the view because you have not reassigned it in the `catch` block. Your approach is awful and you cannot not have a `ViewBag` property with the same name as you model property. Create a view model with a property `SelectList DepartmentList`, assign the select list to it and use the strongly typed helper - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentID, Model.DepartmentList)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers!
The problem was solved with the following code.

VIEW

```
@Html.DropDownList("staff_departmentId", 
    ViewBag.DepartID as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, String.Empty)
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult staffInsert()
{
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
        objDir.getDepartments().Select(d =>
               new SelectListItem
               {
                   Value = d.d_id.ToString(),
                   Text = d.d_name
               });

        ViewBag.DepartID = items;
   return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult staffInsert(staff s)
 {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {                    
        objDir.commitInsertS(s);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      catch
      {
        return View();
      }
   }

   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
        objDir.getDepartments().Select(d =>
               new SelectListItem
               {
                   Value = d.d_id.ToString(),
                   Text = d.d_name
               });

        ViewBag.DepartID = items;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: This helped me strangely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if you use something like the following instead?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentID, ViewBag.DepartmentID)
```